# Joomla 3! Module Parameters

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla website where I have a custom module with mod_myModuleName.php and mod_myModuleName.xml files and a folder where there are several PHP scripts that add special functionality to my module. There is a config.php file in the folder that holds an associative array with variables and their values hard-coded. The module works just fine.

What I want though is to provide administrator area for the values of the variables in the array, so that I can put values in administrator panel and get their values in config.php. In my mod_myModuleName.php I use `<?php echo $params->get('param')?>` and it works like a charm.

But when I try to use the same technique in the config.php it breaks my code. I tried to get the values in mod_myModuleName.php and then include it in config.php and use the variables but it does not work either. I have not got so much experience in php and cannot understand what can be the reason.

It sometimes gives me an error of something non object and I guess it must be something connected with object oriented php, am I right? And if so is there a way to overcome this without object orientation or how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be with the way you're using your `config.php`.

When your modules entry point file `mod_myModuleName.php` is loaded by Joomla the `$params` object is already available in that context, you need to provide it to your scripts.

If you look at something like the `mod_articles_latest` module you will notice that the helper class is included with this line:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/helper.php';
```

And then helper class is has it's `getList()` method called statically with the `$params` passed into it, so that `$params` is available to class context:

```
$list = ModArticlesLatestHelper::getList($params);
```

Inside the helper class `ModArticlesLatestHelper` you will notice that the `getList()` expects the `$params` to be passed in.

```
public static function getList(&$params)
{
...
}
```

I would strongly recommend reading the articles in the [Modules section](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers#Modules) of [Developers Portal](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) on the [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/).

Try the "Creating a simple module" article.